# Как выбрать из строк, удовлетворяющих условию, вторую сотню?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с большим количеством строк, хочу сделать их просмотр по странично, по 100 записей на странице, как записать запрос, что бы показывались строки с 100 до 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 100,100
```

[Оператор SQL LIMIT](http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-limit/)

Коротко разберем запрос. Если правильно читать синтаксис, то по логике выходит так:

> Извлечь все столбцы из таблицы table, начиная с сотой, в количестве ста штук.

Comment: Спасибо! Видел такое, но сообразил...

Comment: LIMIT пишется до или после ORDER BY&

Comment: @ArtGrek13, да. Выйдет что-то вроде

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column ... LIMIT N,N`